# JAVA Numberline errors

Tags: java

I am trying to make the following number line is Java

```
2,3,5,7,11,13,17 (Prime Numbers)
```

I tried [this code](http://pastebin.com/PUVfeGmX)

```
for(int i =0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i < 2) {
        continue;
    }
    for(int j = 2; j < 1; j++) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }    
    }    
}
```

But it doesn't work
Anyone help please?

Comment: In the second for loop you should have this as your condition: `j < i` instead of  `j < 1`.

Comment: Then this is the number if I put i ,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,9,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,15,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19

Comment: Post all code as code-formatted text with your question please.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**
There are a lot of errors in that code, first of all that second loop is a infinite loop and second one that the `System.out.println` line should not be in second loop it should be at end of first loop! If you place it in second it will print numbers hundreds of time.
This is the correct code :

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)//begin loop from 2 instead of 0
{   
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int j = 2; j < i; j++)
    {
        if(i % j == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }      
    }  
    if(flag)System.out.print(i + ",");
}
```

You need to set a flag to check if a factor was found outside the loop.

Comment: `i` cannot equal `j`, because you are looping `j` up to `i`, not up to and including `i`.

Comment: That will not work - it will print the number either way. Also, the `i != j` part is unnecessary, as `j < i`.

Comment: Indeed, @Nulano, `System.out.print(i + ",");` needs to be put right before `break;`.

Comment: @Gooz No, that would only print non-primes.

Comment: @Zeus IntelliJ compains about the `i != j` and the output is all numbers between 2 and 100 (inclusive).

Comment: @Nulano Oops, indeed. Feeling a bit sleepy I suppose :)

Comment: @Nulano My bad. I corrected the code now it should work. Thanks for notifying buddy and about that i and j I had some confusion with it and thought it will iterate atleast one time even if condition is false as in `do-while`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite poor, but the minimal amount of changes needed to make it work yields this code:

```
outerLoop:
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i < 2) {
        continue;
    }
    for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            continue outerLoop;
        }    
    }    
    System.out.print(i + ",");
}
```

But a further improvement would be to start the first loop at 2 right away:

```
outerLoop:
for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
    for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        // and so on...
```